# PowMod in single step

Tags: rsa

I am trying to figure out if it is known how to calculate PowMod for a specific number of iterations in a single calculation. For instance take following function.

m^e mod N

m is a plaintext value
e is the exponent 
N is the modulus value

there is a need to be able to apply this function repeatedly using the value that it generates as m for the next iteration.  The power of this is that you must calculate each iteration to get the input for the next iteration. But what I am focusing on is the ability to skip a specified number of iterations. It's like going from A to Z instead of a to b to c etc. to z.
So for instance if m=2, e=23 and N=259. And I apply the function three times I get 130. 
2=>116=>205=>130

I am searching to see if there is a known function that will jump from 2 straight to 130 in a single calculation for the example above. but I haven't found anything. Would you know of a good way to find out if this exist?
Let me ask it this way... if you knew the solution, what would you do with it?

Comment: Binary exponentiation  may help you.

Comment: My understanding is that is used to calculate exponents for very large numbers.

Comment: You can use binary exponentiation for arbitrary numbers(small and large).

Comment: But exponentiation only calculates what a number raised toanother number is. What I have done, is to come up with a way to do a PowMod on a number and use the result as the input to PowMod again and so on for a specific number of iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$((m^e\bmod N)^e\bmod N)^e\bmod N\;=\;m^{(e^3)}\bmod N\;=\;m^{(e^3\bmod\lambda(N))}\bmod N$$where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).